# Slider Navigation with arrows (HTML,CSS,JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a slider navigation like this:

[image]

Currently what I can achieve right now is this

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .slider {
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .slides {
    display: flex;
    
    overflow-x: auto;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    
    
    
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    
    /*
    scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(300px);
    scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
    */
  }
  .slides::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
  }
  .slides::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: black;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  .slides::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: transparent;
  }
  .slides > div {
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #eee;
    transform-origin: center center;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    position: relative;
    
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 100px;
  }
  .slides > div:target {
  /*   transform: scale(0.8); */
  }
  .author-info {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    color: white;
    padding: 0.75rem;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .author-info a {
    color: white;
  }
  img {
    object-fit: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .slider > a {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: 1.5rem;
    background: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
    position: relative;
  }
  .slider > a:active {
    top: 1px;
  }
  .slider > a:focus {
    background: #000;
  }
  
  /* Don't need button navigation */
  @supports (scroll-snap-type) {
    .slider > a {
      display: none;
    }
  }
  
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #74ABE2, #5563DE);
    font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif;
  }
```

```html
   <div class="slider">
  
    <a href="#slide-1">1</a>
    <a href="#slide-2">2</a>
    <a href="#slide-3">3</a>
    <a href="#slide-4">4</a>
    <a href="#slide-5">5</a>
  
    <div class="slides">
      <div id="slide-1">
        1
      </div>
      <div id="slide-2">
        2
      </div>
      <div id="slide-3">
        3
      </div>
      <div id="slide-4">
        4
      </div>
      <div id="slide-5">
        5
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But what I need exactly is the image above. How to achieve that? I am just new to frontend, so basically I am still learning when it comes to css from scratch.

Comment: Hello. Do you need back and next arrows?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov yes precisely

Comment: instead of clicking them i'll just use the next and back arrows to show the next content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jquery](https://jquery.com/) And Add some CSS

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
  var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
  var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
  var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

  $('#slider').css({
    width: slideWidth,
    height: slideHeight
  });

  $('#slider ul').css({
    width: sliderUlWidth,
    marginLeft: -slideWidth
  });

  $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

  function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
      left: +slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
      $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
  };

  function moveRight() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
      left: -slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
      $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
  };

  $('a.control_prev').click(function() {
    moveLeft();
  });

  $('a.control_next').click(function() {
    moveRight();
  });

});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600);
html {
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  background: #58DDAF;
  color: #2a2a2a;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 39px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 10%;
  height: 33%;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

a.control_prev,
a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 2%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.control_prev:hover,
a.control_next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

a.control_next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">>></a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev">
    <</a>
      <ul>
        <li>SLIDE 1</li>
        <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
        <li>SLIDE 3</li>
        <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not the slider I wanted . I am sorry

Comment: Did you try adding css styles ?

Comment: can this be done by not using jquery sir? I'll mark your answer as correct because wordpress is not accepting jquery . I've been trying to implement jquery on wordpress but not working

Comment: We Can use it in wordpress ! Replace the Jquery  $ Sign With JQuery

Comment: I don't quite understand your last remark sir

Comment: I am using this plugin Custom CSS & JS for all those custom css and js

Comment: For example replace `$("#d").remove()` with `jQuery("#d").remove()`

Comment: And  also import jquery script using `wp_enque_script` hook

Comment: one last question sir . where can i find this wp_enque_script hook

Comment: This is the script that used to enqueue custom scripts to the frontend. see it here (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

Comment: Dear sir did you added css styles ?